# How can I check my favorated commands from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

Is there way any I can see the how many number of times A command has got executed in my terminal with count on it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open your terminal and type as

```
history | awk '{a[$2]++} END { for  ( i in a ) { print a[i] " " i}}' | sort -rn | head
```

Then that will give you most executed commands in your terminal.

For example:

```
raja@debian:~$ history | awk '{a[$2]++} END { for  ( i in a ) { print a[i] " " i}}' | sort -rn | head
45 sudo
20 firefox
10 ./configure
9 ls
9 ./hotspot.sh
9 cd
8 nano
6 su
5 man
4 vmstat
```